# Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $s_n=(-1)^n$, then $\text{lim} |s_n|$ exists, but $\text{lim} s_n$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $s_n=(-1)^n$, then $\text{lim} |s_n|$ exists, but $\text{lim} s_n$ does not exist.

It looks obvious that given $s_n=(-1)^n$, we get left side of the limit equal to the right side of the limit for $|s_n|$ and left side of the limit $\neq$ of the limit right when we have $\text{lim} s_n$. How can I formally prove the problem?

Comment: What does "left side" and "right side" even mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s_n=(-1)^n,$ then $|s_n|=1$, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|s_n|=1$, because, for $n>0, ||s_n|-1|=0,$

which is less than any $\epsilon>0$.

On the other hand, $|s_n-s_{n-1}|=2, $ so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} s_n$ does not converge by Cauchy's test.